# Ansible integer variables in YAML

Tags: yaml, jinja2, ansible

I'm using Ansible to deploy a webapp. I'd like to wait for the application to be running by checking that a given page returns a JSON with a given key/value.

I want the task to be tried a few times before failing. I'm therefore using the combination of `until`/`retries`/`delay` keybwords.

Issue is, I want the number of `retries` to be taken from a variable. If I write :

```
  retries: {{apache_test_retries}}
```

I fall into the usual Yaml Gotcha (http://docs.ansible.com/YAMLSyntax.html#gotchas).

If, instead, I write:

```
  retries: "{{apache_test_retries}}"
```

I'm being said the value is not an integer.

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{{apache_test_retries}}'

Here is my full code:

```
- name: Wait for the application to be running
  local_action:
    uri
    url=http://{{webapp_url}}/health
    timeout=60
  register: res
  sudo: false
  when: updated.changed and apache_test_url is defined
  until: res.status == 200 and res['json'] is defined and res['json']['status'] == 'UP'
  retries: "{{apache_test_retries}}"
  delay: 1
```

Any idea on how to work around this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to say that, if I write `retries: apache_test_retries`, I get the same `invalid literal for int()` error.

Comment: What version of ansible are you using? There have been changes to variables & filters in different versions.

Comment: I'm using version 1.8.2.

Comment: Ah, looks like this issue has already been reported: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5865

Answer (score 37):

I had the same issue and tried a bunch of things that didn't work so for some time I just worked around without using a variable but found the answer so for everyone who has it.

Daniels solution indeed should work:

```
retries: "{{ apache_test_retries | int }}"
```

However, if you are running a little older version of Ansible it won't work. So make sure you **update** Ansible. I tested on **1.8.4** and it works and it doesn't on 1.8.2

This was the original bug on ansible:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5865

Comment: When passing an int value through multiple variables, ansible may convert the value to string afterwards despite using `|int`. Setting [jinja2_native=True](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-jinja2-native) fixes that. Not relevant to OP, but relevant to people arriving here from searching the web.

Comment: @TimDiels Thank you so much for pointing that out. You saved my day

Answer (score 16):

You should be able to convert it to an integer with the [int filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#int):

```
retries: "{{ apache_test_retries | int }}"
```

Comment: Same issue, unfortunately: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{{ apache_test_retries | int }}'`

Comment: If you see this error it could be because you do something like `{{ some_var / 10 | int }}` which will actually parse as ``{{ some_var / (10 | int) }}`` so you need `{{ (some_var / 10) | int }}`. Other than that `| int` works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the solutions suggested here didn't work. I didn't try Tim Diels' suggestion though.

Here's what worked for me:

```
vars:
capacity: "{{ param_capacity | default(16) }}"

tasks:
- name: some task
  ...
  when: item.usage < (capacity | int)
  loop:
  ...
```

And here's what I was trying to do:

```
vars:
capacity: "{{ (param_capacity | default(16)) | int }}"

tasks:
- name: some task
  ...
  when: item.usage < capacity
  loop:
  ...
```

I found [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13574), about this same problem, and actually the intended way to use this filter is applying it where you use the variable, not where you declare it.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue, in my case I wanted to restart `celeryd` service. It sometimes takes a very long time to restart and I wanted to give it max 30 seconds for a soft restart, then force-restart it. I used `async` for this (polling for restart result every 5 seconds).

`celery/handlers/main.yml`

```
- name: restart celeryd
  service:
    name=celeryd
    state=restarted
  register: celeryd_restart_result
  ignore_errors: true
  async: "{{ async_val | default(30) }}"
  poll: 5

- name: check celeryd restart result and force restart if needed
  shell: service celeryd kill && service celeryd start
  when: celeryd_restart_result|failed
```

And then I use above in the playbook as handlers to a task (`restart celeryd` is always first in `notify` list)

---

In your case something like below could possibly work. Haven't checked whether it does but it might give you some hack idea to solve it in a different way. Also since you will be ignoring errors in the 1st task, you need to make sure that things are fine in 2nd:

```
- name: Poll to check if the application is running
  local_action:
    uri
    url=http://{{webapp_url}}/health
    timeout=60
  register: res
  sudo: false
  when: updated.changed and apache_test_url is defined
  failed_when: res.status != 200 and res['json'] is not defined and not res['json']['status'] == 'UP'
  ignore_errors: true
  async: "{{ apache_test_retries | default(60) }}"
  poll: 1

  # Task above will exit as early as possible on success
  # It will keep trying for 60 secs, polling every 1 sec
  # You need to make sure it's fine **again** because it has ignore_errors: true

- name: Final UP check
  local_action:
    uri
    url=http://{{webapp_url}}/health
    timeout=60
  register: res
  sudo: false
  when: updated.changed and apache_test_url is defined
  failed_when: res.status != 200 and res['json'] is not defined and not res['json']['status'] == 'UP'
```

Hope it helps you solve the issue with a bug in `retries`.

Comment: Wow, I had already tried a similar option and your suggestion looked very promising. Issue is, the `async` option is for long running commands and the task ends right after the first request. Also, the `ignore_errors` option seems to be conflicting with the `failed_when` one. No luck this time :(

Comment: You're right, too bad... :/ Guess it might be best to push for #5865 bug fix on GitHub... it's been there for a while however being tagged as P3 I wouldn't expect it to be merged quickly. Too much hacking right now to get a simple thing done.